# Regex - match multiple suffix(longer or shorter)

Tags: sql, regex, powershell

I'm currently stuck on an issue with powershell regex since I am not able to get the desired output of Servername, instance name, and port if available. Admittedly, I have much to understand since I am new with regex.

Here is my setup and my findings so far

```
Data:

  ZP000042
  QRMLD1001\TEST
  oFJA
  UUQE0294\FAR,8594
```

Basically I need to extract the following items:

```
Match 1[QRMLD1001\TEST] - Servername: QRMLD1001 ; Instancename: TEST

Match 2[UUQE0294\FAR,8594] - Servername: UUQE0294 ; Instancename: FAR ; Port: 8594
```

So far I am only able to extract `Match 2[ UUQE0294\FAR,859` ] via this regex

```
(\w+)\\(\w+)\,(\d+)
```

Result:

```
Groups   : {0, 1, 2, 3}
Success  : True
Name     : 0
Captures : {0}
Index    : 0
Length   : 16
Value    : UUQE0294\FAR,859

Success  : True
Name     : 1
Captures : {1}
Index    : 0
Length   : 8
Value    : UUQE0294

Success  : True
Name     : 2
Captures : {2}
Index    : 9
Length   : 3
Value    : FAR

Success  : True
Name     : 3
Captures : {3}
Index    : 13
Length   : 3
Value    : 859
```

I really just want to either have 3 to 4 groups, this means that with or without the port specified, i'd like to dissect the server and instance name, and if the port is included, then the port too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a quantifier that allows 0 occurrances after the `,` and the last number, like so

```
(\w+)\\(\w+)\,?(\d*)
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks @Lance Toth. that ? is really what's missing huh! Quick follow-up, is it possible to eliminate the blank/null Group 4 when the port isnt specified? 

e.g.
[QRMLD1001\TEST] still gives 4 groups with the last one set as null.

Comment: @CarlArdiente I don't know of any way, sorry

Answer (score 1):

I simple way would be to make the whole latter part of the pattern optional.

```
(\w+)\\(\w+)(,(\d+))?
```

So that would match both of these

```
UUQE0294\FAR,8594
UUQE0294\FAR
```

You could make this a little more robust with some lookbehinds but there is not much to gain here. Just note that your match groups will need to be adjusted since there is one more there. You can make that part a little easier as well by using named matches

```
(?<server>\w+)\\(?<instance>\w+)(,(?<port>\d+))?
```

So now you can do this and not have to worry about group indexes.

```
$matches.server
$matches.instance
$matches.port
```

If there is no match for port then `$matches.port` would just be null.

Comment: Thanks a lot man! named groups and lookbehind is something new to me, so thank you for pointing that out! I've made a slight modification of your Regex to `(?<server>\w+)\\(?<instance>\w+)\,(?<port>\d+)?` since the original one you posted actually gives me another group with the comma [e.g. ,8594]

Comment: @CarlArdiente But I thought the comma was optional? Also the first option has a group without the comma so you just skip it. Look at what matches returns and you will see.